# DLL locking on deploy to Azure Deployment slot with NewRelic

Tags: .net, azure-web-app-service, newrelic, azure-devops

I am deploying from Visual Studio Team Services to an Azure deployment slot. This deployment slot has New Relic disabled (`COR_ENABLE_PROFILING = 0`). Once deployed, the slot automatically swaps with production where New Relic is enabled. Despite this, I still get the DLL locking issue. I don't understand why DLLs would be locked for NewRelic when NewRelic is disabled, but the problem is still there.

We have tried using NuGet and site extensions, but no luck. We haven't even upgraded NewRelic recently and the locking should only occur on upgrades, correct?

Any ideas how we can get around this issue? We are considering moving to some other framework that doesn't have these problems.

Answer (score 1):

A recommended workaround for this from NewRelic is installing the agent into your app by using the New Relic Site Extension.

> 1.Navigate to http://[yoursite].scm.azurewebsites.net/ and select Site Extensions.
>
> 2.From the Gallery, select + and then select New Relic.
>
> 3.Follow the instructions for Configuration key values to manually add the configuration keys to your web app, and use the option that best
>   fits your needs.
>
> You should only have to install the Extension once. To update the
>   extension: From the Azure Portal, select WebApps > (selected site) >
>   All Settings > Extensions > New Relic.

Refer to this link for details: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-web-apps

Comment: I'm well aware of that and have had no luck with it.

Comment: Since the file is already been locked, did you try to stop the web app service, remove New Relic from your local web app and then deploy it. And then install the site extension?

Comment: Yes. I have some sites with the site extension, some without, but both with New Relic disabled. I even deleted the newrelic directory, did a deployment slot swap and deleted the newrelic directory there. Publish a few more times and the problem eventually comes back. Next step is to remove the DLLs completely from my project. I have seen this in any of the instructions, but I'll try anything at this point, even if that means discontinuing use of New Relic and finding something else.